# Magento 2 Knockout JS (access UiClass from foreach)

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have a question about my knockout ViewModel. I can't access "this" in my jumpToPage (defined in ViewModel) from my click in the template. The subscribeToQuery displays "this" as a UiClass so that i can access other methods from there. I would like to do the same from my jumpToPage method.

Below is my viewmodel:

```
define(['jquery','ko', 'uiComponent'], function ($, ko, Component) {
        "use strict";
        self.addresses = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.pages = ko.observable(0);
        self.q = ko.observable("");
        return Component.extend({
            initialize : function() {
                this._super();
                this.getAddresses();
                this.subscribeToQuery();
            },
            getAddresses : function(search, page, limit) {
                self.addresses([]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/customer/addresses',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        p: (page === undefined) ? 1 : page,
                        limit: (limit === undefined) ? 10 : limit,
                        search: search
                    },
                    complete: function (output) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(output.responseText);
                        $.each(json.data, function(index, address) {
                            self.addresses.push(address);
                        });
                        self.pages(json.meta.pages);
                    }
                });
            },
            subscribeToQuery : function() {
                console.log(this);
                var that = this;
                self.q.subscribe(function(value) {
                    clearTimeout(self.addressCall);
                    self.addressCall = setTimeout(function () {
                        that.getAddresses(value);
                    }, 300);
                });
            },
            jumpToPage : function(item, event) {
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And this is my template:

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Zoek een adres" data-bind="value: q, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
<br />
<br />
<table data-bind="foreach: addresses">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 2px solid #e0e0e0; background-color: #efefef; border-radius: 10px;">
            <h3 data-bind="text: company"></h3>
            <small data-bind="text: firstname"></small>
            <small data-bind="text: lastname"></small>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td style="height: 2px;"></td></tr>
</table>

<div data-bind="foreach: new Array(pages())">
    <button data-bind="text: $index()+1, click: $parent.jumpToPage" style="cursor: pointer"></button>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

old post but this might help someone.

You just need to define a global variable before extending your component and assign the component context in initialize.

Then you can you **self** in your function.

```
define(['jquery','ko', 'uiComponent'], function ($, ko, Component) {
    ...
    var self;
    ...
    return Component.extend({
        initialize : function() {
         self = this;
    ...

        jumpToPage : function(item, event) {
          self. subscribeToQuery();
            console.log(this);
        }
```